# How to properly invalidate the hibernate 2nd level cache from outside a hibernate transaction

Tags: hibernate, caching, jdbctemplate

We're working on an application which is using Hibernate 2 (a legacy portion which was never updated).  Part of this application uses a JdbcTemplate to do a series of updates.  These updates occur outside the context of any hibernate transaction.  Since the updates affect objects that are already in the 2nd level cache, we are getting side effects with invalid data being displayed from cache.

We need to invalidate / clear the hibernate cache.  What is the right way to do this using Hibernate 2?  Remember we're updating objects outside of a hibernate transaction and after the updates are complete we want to invalidate the cache or refresh the cache so that it reflects up to date data.

We're having trouble finding information on this seeing as how it's Hibernate 2 vs the more current version 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessionFactory.getCache()` (or `entityManagerFactory.getCache()` to access the 2nd level cache